# tf to tf2 SendTransform type error

Tags: ros, python, tf2-ros, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on some forked code that is setup for tf and on my BeagleBone Black I only have tf2. I have most of the code working but it is erroring out on sendtransform with

TypeError: sendTransform() takes exactly 2 arguments (6 given)

I am not sure what to change to the new format. I haven't found a way to get the recipe to cross compile tf. But in the long run it would be better to convert over.

I am working on base_controller.py on my github account FriedCircuits\Ros_Arduino_bridge
(can't post links yet)

Any help to convert it to tf2 would be great. I haven working on this for weeks on the BBB and I am pretty close to having something functional.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/94136/tf-to-tf2-sendtransform-type-error/) by [MobileWill](https://answers.ros.org/users/8101/mobilewill/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-10-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like it now takes a TransformStamped() message, rather than individual args.  The docs & tutorials seem to be older than the hydro code.  For example:

```
transform = TransformStamped(header=Header(stamp=rospy.Time.now(), frame_id="parent"),
                             transform=Transform(translation=Vector3(x,y,z),
                                                 rotation=Quaternion(qx,qy,qz,qw)),
                             child_frame_id="child"
                            )
self.tfbx.sendTransform(transform)
```

---

Originally posted by [ssafarik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1687/ssafarik/) with karma: 306 on 2013-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0